# React Native Reference being passed instead on value in JSX,Element Array

Tags: reactjs, types, reference, native

I am new to React native so this might be kind of a silly question. So I am trying to make a photo gallery app in React Native. I retrieve links from a webpage in JSON format and display them in the gallery. Now I am using a JSX.Element array to save the format of the thumbnails in the gallery and I and using the TouchableHighlight to call a function in its onPress property.

```js
      tempImageArray.push(
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={()=>this._onPressButton(indexNumber)}>            
        <Image source={{uri : this.state.dataSource}}/>
        </TouchableHighlight>);
```

Now the problem that I am facing is that whenever I tap on the touchable element the _OnPressButton function responds to the current value of indexNumber instead of what it was at the time of pushing it in the array. So I am guessing the the reference of indexNumber is being passed to the array instead of its value. I would like to pass the value of indexNumber.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are iterating on top of `push` operation. If so - it is classic javascript closure problem. Please provide more code to make it easier to jump into context and run your snippets. All below is pseudocode examples.

Use autorun anonymous function to store `indexNumber` in a closure:

```js
tempImageArray.push(
    <TouchableHighlight onPress={((storedNumber)=> (event) => this._onPressButton(storedNumber))(indexNumber)}>            
    <Image source={{uri : this.state.dataSource}}/>
    </TouchableHighlight>);
```

Or, to make it easier to read and maintain, encapsulate handler creation in a separate method:

```js
     _makePressButtonHandler = (indexNumber) => (event) => { 
         this._onPressButton(indexNumber) 
     }
     _onPressButton = (indexNumber) => { 
       // ...do something 
     }

     // somewheare in render method:

    tempImageArray.push(
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={this._makePressButtonHandler(indexNumber)}>            
      <Image source={{uri : this.state.dataSource}}/>
      </TouchableHighlight>);
```